# Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)

Tags: android-studio

[image] I am getting this in my Log cat Window from last week. What if I will update? I am little nervous if new version will be different from which i m using Android 1.5.1

After pressing "Available" in Log Cat I get[image]

What to do now.?

Answer (score 1):

Change is always good in the long run.

If the new version is a stable version,you should switch.You can check latest stable build [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html).

You can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBbWGxXCMqQ) video to run 2 different versions parallely if you want to have a preview

You can see [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html) to see what has been updated .

Android Studio 2.0 has instant run for builds which will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Update wouldn't change IDE drastically. You will only get newly features which are added in every updated addition.

like Android Studio v2.0.0 has Instant Run feature

> Android Studio now deploys clean builds faster than ever before.
>   Additionally, pushing incremental code changes to the emulator or a
>   physical device is now almost instantaneous. Review your updates
>   without redeploying a new debug build or, in many cases, without
>   restarting the app.

Read [Android Studio Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html).